# can listview supports horizontal scrolling text

Tags: android, listview, scroll

hai,
     i have custom listview in that page should have the horizontal scrolling text. But the horizontal text is not scrolling. so please help me anyone.

i used following xml code.

```
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text=""
    android:layout_x="2px"
    android:layout_y="690px"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_1"
    android:textColor="#cc0000"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"    
    android:ellipsize="marquee"   
    />
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't "ellipsize" a typo?  Don't you mean "ellipsis"?

Answer (score 0):

set listview focusable is false

```
listview.setfocusable(false);
```